# Incorrect string value for column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I'm getting this error while trying to save an entry from my application to mysql DB

> Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; uncategorized
>   SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366];
>   Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BShe...' for column
>   'extracted_text' at row 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BShe...' for column
>   'extracted_text' at row 1
>           at com.some.scanner.RequestService.$tt__handleMessage(RequestService.groovy:67)

My Table is created as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `request` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `doc_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extracted_text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK414EF28FD3E87920` (`batch_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20025 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

my entity mapping is quite simple in Grails

```
class Request {
  String docHash
  String extractedText

  static mapping = {
    extractedText type: 'text'
  }
}
```

Do I need to change the encoding type? If so, to what?

Comment: Please add your Entity mapping class

Answer (score 1):

Set the database properties `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding`. These are passed directly to your JDBC driver: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html#getDbProperties%28%29

```
dataSource {
  url = 'jdbc:mysql://...'
  properties {
    dbProperties {
      useUnicode=true
      characterEncoding='UTF-8'
     }
  }
}
```

A little more about MySQL Connect charsets (which includes the spelling of `UTF-8`): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

MySQL-specific config properties go in `dbProperties`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

...unless they are already covered by the main `dataSource` properties from: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource
or are in the "extra" `properties` from: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: I have these set in my jdbcUrl . `jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8` that is why table created code posted in my question uses `utf8`

Comment: Sorry fot the delay. You can try adding `character_set_server='utf8mb4'` and leave out the `characterEncoding`, as mentioned in the MySQL docs linked above. Also, this UTF non-breaking space in particular seems to be a bug in some CKEditor versions. Try up- or down-grading that if you are using it, and maybe you can keep UTF-8.